# Breakpoint in ROS_ASSERT

Tags: ros, gdb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to set a debug breakpoint in ROS_ASSERT (gdb, Eclipse..) which only stops the program execution if the assertion fails so I can inspect the stack when the assertion fails?

It would work, if it would be like this:

```
if ( !( cond ) )
{
 ROS_ASSERT( cond );  // set breakpoint here
}
```

But without the surrounding if statement, the ROS_ASSERT is only in one line, and if I set a breakpoint there it will stop always, not only if the assertion fails.....

Any ideas on this? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185165/breakpoint-in--ros_assert/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2014-07-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-07**:
ROS_ASSERT calls abort(). You might be able to trap that directly.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-07-07**:
+1 Works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @dornhege stated ROS_ASSERT calls abort. The SIGABRT can be trapped directly using gdb (in my case it even did by default;) ).  Note that the thereby the SIGABRT is handled, so the process 'survives' the ROS_ASSERT. You still need to kill it via gbd....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0